# simple statistics (binomial) terminology

Tags: terminology, statistics, discrete-math

Say I have the problem: I roll a die three times and I am interested in the probability of ending up with two 1's.

My impression is that a single roll is called a trial.

What is the full 3-roll action called? I thought it was called an experiment, but I've seen experiment used synonymous with trial.

Using the binomial distribution, we call getting a 1 here a "success" and getting anything else a "failure." This might confuse students who think it's a "failure" to get three 1's. Is there an alternative/better way to say this acquiring of a 1 vs. not a 1?

Comment: "*ending up with two 1's*"  Do you mean *exactly* two or *at least* two?

Comment: I mean exactly two 1's.

Comment: You should edit your post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

- You might point out that the $3$-trial experiment has $8$ possible
  outcomes and $256$ possible events, which are subsets of the sample
  space; whereas each trial has $2$ possible outcomes, which can be
  contextually characterised as a success and a failure.

  To distinguish between trial outcomes and experiment outcomes (or to
  remind about their distinction), I sometimes call the former
  “sub-outcomes” and the latter “elementary events”. When introducing
  the terminology, I indicate that “sub-outcome” is a nonstandard word
  (actually, I coined it).
- To directly address your question:

  I would point out that the assignments ‘success’ & ‘failure’
  naturally arise out of Bernoulli trials having exactly two outcomes
  of fixed probabilities.

  In contrast, it is not so useful to call the
  event $\{n11,1n1,11n\}$ or its outcomes “successes”; moreover, we might be
  interested in multiple events in the experiment, in which case the notion of a
  “successful” event (or elementary event) will have to keep varying according to the event being considered.

Comment: So you agree that experiment is the word for the full 3-roll activity, and is not synonymous with trial?

Comment: Apparently my stats are rusty because I don't know where you're getting 256. Do you mean 216 (6*6*6)?

Comment: @Nights 1. Yes. And given enough discussion time, I might also point out that while any two trials of this experiment are independent of each other, two events with reference to this experiment could be either dependent or independent. $\quad$2. The sample space has $2^3=8$ members/outcomes and thus $2^8=256$ subsets/events.

Comment: There are six outcomes in a trial: 1 - 6. When you write out every possibility you have 216 possible 3-die rolls. I thought that THIS constitutes the sample space (I haven't opened the class textbook yet, but this is what I remember.) The probability is calculated by hand by finding the number of rolls which give two 1's, where a roll (1,1,2) is different from a roll of (1,1,3), for example, and dividing this number by 216. Where are you getting this other use of the term "sample space" in terms of success/failure only? And what's the significance of your power set calculation?

Comment: 1. In your ***binomial model***, each trial has exactly two possible outcomes: ‘1’ (success) and ‘n’ (failure, whose likelihood here is five times that of success). The game can of course be *reframed* as a different probability experiment in which each trial has six equally-likely outcomes; in this model, the experiment indeed has $6^3=216$ outcomes.

Comment: 2. In your binomial model, your desired event (getting exactly two ‘1’s, i.e., $\{n11,1n1,11n\}$) is one of $256$ possible events; for example, the event of getting at least two ‘1’s $=\{n11,1n1,11n,111\},$ while the event of getting all ‘1’s $=\{111\}.$  OTOH, the second model above has $2^{216}$ associated events.